# Deploying .car file (packaged with .war file) in wso2 server

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I am trying to deploy carbon archieve file (*.car) in wso2 ESB server.For this purpose First I am creating carbon application project in my wso2 dev studio.Then after selecting this project tried to create a web application(war file).But not able to see in the context menu options either to create a new war file or to import an existing war file.
Can somebody clarify me is it possible to deploy .war file (packaged as .car file) in the wso2 ESB server? (After configuring the server role for Application Server in the WSO2 ESB).

Answer (score 1):

WSO2 ESB (Enterprise Service Bus ) is middle-ware product which is used for message routing , mediation and transformation etc. I think you can use WSO2 Application Server for deploying WAR file and use as Web/application server in your back-end.

You can download WSO2AS from  http://wso2.com/products/application-server/

Also  how to deploy WAR file in WSO2AS is explained here.
http://wso2.com/library/articles/2012/09/develop-deploy-web-applications-using-wso2-developer-studio/

Comment: By default WSO2 ESB does not support deploying Web-Applications and for that as Jayalal has mentioned you can use WSO2 Application Server. In order to deploy Web-Applications in WSO2 ESB, you need to install Application Deployment Carbon Feature on top of your WSO2 ESB instance and customize it.